# json dat from API REST

Tags: php, arrays, json

From my API call I get data in JSON format
Now I want use these data and create these code

```
<?php
$result  = json_decode($content);

echo $result->price;
?>
```

But this shows not the price.

If I do

```
<?php
$result  = json_decode($content);
print_r($result);
?>
```

I got these data below

```
[short_description] => [sku] => 3463031 [price] => 144.00 [regular_price] => 144.00 [sale_price] => [date_on_sale_from] =>
```

How can I get for example the price?

Comment: use `json_decode($content,true);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using associative arrays is simpler when working with JSON especially when you have nested JSON.

If your JSON object nested like below:

```
{
"short_description":{
"sku":3463031,
"price":144.00,
...
}
}
```

you can access it using:

```
$result=json_decode($content,true);  //true converts returned object to an associative array
echo $result['short_description']['price'];
```

if not use below:

```
$result=json_decode($content,true);  //true converts returned object to an associative array
echo $result['price'];
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.